# predict() in R returning too many values (multilinear regression)

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict

I found other matching questions but those are for univariate ones, and the one I found for multivariate one didn't work. I'm quite frustrated because this shouldn't be taking hours to figure out. Here's the code:

```
sample_spxx=spxx[2:150]
sample_x=x[1:149,]
y=lm(sample_spxx~sample_x)

test_spxx=spxx[151:207]
test_x=x[150:206,]

predict(y,newdata=data.frame(DTWEXBGS=x[1,1],CFNAI=x[2,1],DGS2=x[3,1],BAMLH0A0HYM2=x[4,1],CPIAUCSL=x[5,1]))
```

which goes on to generate 149 predictions which is quite mind blowing. Names used above are the column names for the data frame x because one of the answers said to use the same names.

Another way I tried is:

```
predictions=c()

for(i in 1:nrow(test_x)){
  
  predictions[i]=predict(y,sample_x=data.frame(test_x[i,]))
}
```

which also messes up completely. Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: Are you trying to get predictions for `test_x`?

Comment: Yes @user2974951

Comment: `predict(text_x)`?

Comment: That returns 149 predictions, which is just train set predictions. '''predict(y,as.data.frame(test_x))''' @user2974951

Comment: You must use the data argument of lm if you want to predict for newdata.

Comment: @Roland I don't understand - use it where? and what particularly is the data argument of LM? There are two data sets fed to LM.

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible example, my guess is with the way you use the formula in lm. Put all the variables in one data frame and use the formula as it's supposed to be used.

Comment: `fit <- lm(y ~ ., data = data.frame(sample_x, y = sample_spxx))` and ensure that the data.frame passed to `newdata` within `predict` contains columns with exactly the same names as the columns of `sample_x`.